# FFMPEG Removing audio from video makes the video short

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I was trying to remove audio from video using FFmpeg, the command I used is:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -an -c copy no_sound.mp4
```

But the length of the final video is less than the original video.

Original Video Length - 0:05:43
Final Vidoe Length - 0:05:34

Following is the output generated by FFmpeg:

```
    ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -an -c copy no_sound.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
  Duration: 00:05:42.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 99 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 816x688 [SAR 1:1 DAR 51:43], 64 kb/s, 1.75 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'no_sound.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 816x688 [SAR 1:1 DAR 51:43], q=2-31, 64 kb/s, 1.75 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  584 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2629kB time=00:05:34.53 bitrate=  64.4kbits/s speed=5.78e+04x    
video:2621kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.313674%
```

Why is this happening?

[orignal video file link](https://spoken-tutorial.org/media/videos/61/605/Command-line-arguments-in-C-English.mp4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video stream is variable frame rate and the last frame has a timestamp of 5m34s. The audio is longer. Players will hold on the last frame till the longest stream (audio in this case) has been fully played.

The extraction is fine.

Comment: Thanks, How can I extend the last frame till audio stops?

Comment: You have to use tpad filter and thus re-encode the video and add shortest flags as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804507