# Python convert mp3 to mp4 with static image

Tags: python, unix, ffmpeg

I do have `x` file which contain a list of `mp3` files where i would like to convert each `mp3` file to `mp4` file with a `static` `.png` photo.

Seems the only way here is to use `ffmpeg` but idk how to achieve it.

i made the script to take an input of `mp3` folder and one `.png` photo`.

then it's will create new folder `x-converted` where i would like to convert each `mp3` to `mp4` with the static `png` with *same name* such as `file1.mp3` to became `file1.mp4`

here's my code :

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

if len(sys.argv) != 3 or not sys.argv[2].endswith("png"):
    print("Make sure to provide two arguments only\nSecond arugment should be .png")
    exit()


def CheckFile():
    try:
        files = []
        for path in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
            full_path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], path)
            if os.path.isfile(full_path):
                files.append(full_path)
        mp3 = [x for x in files if x.endswith(".mp3")]
        if len(mp3) >= 1:
            return mp3, sys.argv[2], sys.argv[1]
        else:
            print(
                "Make Sure That You've at least 1 Mp3 file")
            exit()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Sorry, This File Is Not Exist!")
        exit()


def Convert():
    mp3, jpg, name = CheckFile()
    name = f"{Path(name).name}-converted"
    shutil.rmtree(name, ignore_errors=True)
    os.mkdir(name)
    os.chdir(name)
    # from here i don't know how to use `ffmpeg`


Convert()
```

Comment: @llogan just the `ffmpeg` part.

Comment: @llogan I've reviewed your profile and seems that you have very well knowledge within `ffmpeg`. hopefully you can help me . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -r 10 -vf "scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)',format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M output.mp4
```

- `-loop 1` makes `input.png` loop indefinitely.
- `-framerate 1` sets `input.png` input frame rate to 1 fps.
- `-map 0 -map 1:a` chooses the video from `image.png` and only the audio from `audio.mp3`. This is needed in case `image.png` is smaller than any album/cover art attached to the MP3. Otherwise it may choose the album/cover art instead. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info.
- `-r 10` sets output frame rate to 10 fps. Setting input to 1 fps and output to 10 fps is for two reasons:

  - It is faster to input as 1 fps and duplicate frames to 10 fps compared to initially setting the input as 10 fps. It makes encoding faster.
  - Most players can't play anything under ~6 fps or so. 10 is a safe value.
- `scale='iw-mod(iw,2)':'ih-mod(ih,2)'` uses [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to make sure the output width and height are both divisible by 2 which is a requirement for some encoders. This allows you to use any arbitrarily sized image as an input. Otherwise you can get error: `width not divisible by 2`.
- `format=yuv420p` [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) makes output use YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling for playback compatibility.
- `-movflags +faststart` makes the video start playing faster.
- `-shortest` makes the output as long as `audio.mp3`. This is needed because `-loop 1` was used.
- `-fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M` related to `-shortest` and needed in some cases due to weird behavior by ffmpeg. See [My ffmpeg output always add extra 30s of silence at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804507/) for an explanation.

Comment: thank you very very much. such answer really should be in documentation. this is the best explained answer which i ever found

Comment: if you don't mind to check that as i noticed the length of video became long. that's the [original](https://vocaroo.com/1oKr3cJi7uca) and that's after [converting](https://streamable.com/y08icg). i used the same command as you explained without any edit from my end.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη See updated answer (last bullet point). Nice video, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

certain library like `ffmpy` & `ffmpeg-python` can enable you operate ffmpeg with python, try these out. (I used ffmpeg-python long time ago and it worked well)