# Convert one PNG image to webm video with transparency and fade in and out effect

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I have an image named `c.png` 
First I convert it to webm with transparency, use command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/9 -i c.png  -i c.mp3 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p -lossless 1 out.webm
```

Then I want add fade in and fade out to out.webm, but I used many command like this still not working:

```
ffmpeg  -i out.webm -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy out_ok.webm
ffmpeg -i out.webm -vf "fade=in:0:3:alpha=1" out3.webm

ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i out.webm -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1" out_ok.webm

ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i out.webm -filter_complex "fade=t=in:st=0:d=3:alpha=1" -map "[v]" -lossless 1  -b 10M -r 30 all.web
```

How do I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, `.webm` is a format that can be video or image. Changing the format of the image doesn't magically turn it into a video. Your video should have a duration; then you can add effects.

Comment: you mean I need to use 
- t ?

Comment: Are there any other suggested builds?
Or am I missing something here?

Any help is very much appreciated indeed.

Thanks

Comment: Can you test fade effects on another video?

Comment: I test fade effect on mp4 file. It will be working but webm files will not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 1 command. In this example `audio.mp3` is 10 seconds long.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 15 -i input.png -i audio.mp3 -vf "fade=t=in:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:d=1:st=9:alpha=1" -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M output.webm
```

- Your command made an output with only 1 frame of video. Add the `-loop` option to loop the image.
- The `-shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M` options ([see more info about these options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55800185/)) make the video match the audio duration.

Comment: Thank you for your code, the way you provide can achieve the effect.
I made a mistake,  I used IINA app to check the webm files, it will not display the fade effect , but the chrome will.

Comment: @XiangChen if this is the solution that works for you, please accept the answer.